# Magento2 : How to path for background image in .less file?

Tags: magento2, image, less-css

I want to **set path** for **background image** in less file `app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\web\<lessfile>` in magento2.

Comment: This is not an off-topic question. This was very useful for me with Magento 2.

Comment: Yes it is, Thanks :) @Webninja

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First add image in `app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\web\images` folder and write css as below:

```
background: url('@{baseDir}images/icon_sprite.png');
```

after add new image run command as below:

```
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: This is not working for me in Magento 2.1.4. Does this only apply to production mode or should this work in developer mode as well?

Comment: This will work in both mode, just you have to run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command after add image in `app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\web\images` folder. if still not working remove `var/view_preprocessed` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Turned out that my problem was elsewhere. Something to do with corrupt PNG files. Yeah I know, long story... your answer is still correct though. However, you could add that it in some cases it might be necessary to define `@baseDir` in your themes' `theme.less`. By default the variable is set to `../`.

Comment: Thank you ! How about using it this style in _email-extend.less ? and what is the difference with using `background: url("@{baseUrl}images/icn.png');`